# A Directive to link a controller to a form submit. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So here's the scenario: I have multiple newsletter forms throughout a page and I need all of them to execute the same action: Make an AJAX request with some data and, upon request completion, return a message to the user using an alert. So far I have this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('form-newsletter', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link : function($scope, elem) {
              $scope.data = { }
              var $el = elem.find('button[type=submit]');
              $el.on('click' , function(){
                  if (! $scope.data.email ){
                      alert("Please, fill in the e-mail");
                      return false;
                  }
                  if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ){
                      $scope.data.gender = $(this).val();
                  }
                  var data = $scope.data;
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/newsletter/join',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.validation == true) {
                            alert('Thank you for joining our mailing list.');
                        } else {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                  })
                  return false;
              });
          }
        }
 }]);
```

It works as expected, but, as you can see I'm using jQuery ajax method. I wanted to use Angular built-in http, but I can't inject it for some reason. I also tried to make a controller to handle the ajax request but had no success... Any one has any idea of how can I improve this piece of code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the `$http` into the directive so it can be used.

```
myApp.directive('form-newsletter', ['$http',function($http) {
```

I will say, a directive can handle this, but since you aren't really doing DOM manipulation, you could probably do all this in the controller fairly easy using `ngClick` and `ngSubmit`.

Directives are designed to be reusable new HTML elements, providing features, animation, listeners, etc.  They do DOM manipulation and/or listen for events and call specific functions in your controller.

If your code is simply handling a form submission, you could probably do it in the controller.  If it is handling multiple forms on the same page, then a directive would work, or you could modify your controller to handle the forms as well, either way works.

Comment: Quite agree with you Tim, however it often want to automate everything ;-).
Principle of MVC
view: html, view, Directive(dom manage)
controller: model manage, watch event, ...

Comment: Thanks. So I'm probably better off with a controller then? I'll look into it. Thanks. :)